# Unable to trigger Custom Producer Interceptor via JDBC Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have created a custom Producer Interceptor (AuditProducerInterceptor) which accepts some custom configs(application_id, type etc.). I have generated a jar from the AuditProducerInterceptor project and placed the jar inside kafka-connect at /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors. When i try to post JDBC-Source connector with below configurations, my audit interceptor is not triggered.

```
{
"name": "jdbc-source-xx-xxxx-xxx-xxx",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://{{ip}}:1433;databaseName=XX;useNTLMv2=true",
    "connection.user": "SA",
    "connection.password": "Admin1234",
    "producer.interceptor.classes": "com.optum.payer.common.kafka.audit.interceptor.AuditProducerInterceptor",
    "topic.prefix": "MyTestTopic",
    "query": "SELECT ID, chart_id, request_id, UpdatedDate FROM xxx.xxx WITH (NOLOCK)",
    "mode": "timestamp",
    "timestamp.column.name": "UpdatedDate",
    "producer.audit.application.id": "HelloApplication",
    "producer.audit.type": "test type",
    "poll.interval.ms": "10",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "batch.max.rows": "100",
    "validate.non.null": "false",
    "numeric.mapping":"best_fit",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://{{ip}}:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://{{ip}}:8081"
    
}}
```

As u can see in the configuration, i have added below props in connector config to trigger the custom interceptor. But I dont see any logs in Kafka-Connect related to AuditProducerInterceptor.

```
"producer.interceptor.classes": "com.optum.payer.common.kafka.audit.interceptor.AuditProducerInterceptor"
"producer.audit.application.id": "HelloApplication",
"producer.audit.type": "test type"
```

I tried adding these three config in kafka-connect config and I am able to trigger the interceptor. But I want to trigger the interceptor via JDBC source connector so that i can pass the custom props(application_id,type etc) via connector.
Please help me solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have allowed client overrides (enabled by default) in the Connect worker, you'll want to use `producer.override` prefix

From docs

> Starting with 2.3.0, client configuration overrides can be configured individually per connector by using the prefixes `producer.override.` and `consumer.override.` for Kafka sources or Kafka sinks respectively.

Comment: I added CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLIENT_CONFIG_OVERRIDE_POLICY=All in worker config, and i was able to use "producer.override.interceptor.classes": "xxxx". Thanks